# Shorter version of The Merchant of Venice for school play

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, william-shakespeare, the-merchant-of-venice

İs there any short version of the *The Merchant of Venice* to play?
We are going to play it in our class but the problem is that the story is too long and we don't have enough time for all of it. I need a good short version of it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Stack Exchange xoş gəlmisiniz! :-) This question is hovering on the edge of our site scope: [recommendation requests are off-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/17), but your question is about versions of a specific story, so it might be OK. A good search term to use when hunting for short versions is "**abridged**" - e.g. maybe [this](https://www.amazon.com/Merchant-Venice-Abridged-Performance-Shakespeare/dp/1517582873) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorter version of *The Merchant of Venice* by K.J. O'Hara, who has been Artistic Director of the Antic Mind Theatre Company and an English and drama teacher. *The Merchant of Venice: Abridged for Schools and Performance* was published by CreateSpace (Amazon's publishing platform) in 2015.

The goal of the abridgement was to create a version that would be more accessible to a younger audience while still retaining the play's essential elements. In the resulting version,

> the plot is coherent, characters are developed and all the text is original. (...) The abridgement required only one shorter scene to be removed in its entirety; the main revisions have been to cut extraneous dialogue from scenes. This was done partially to allow the play to be performed by a small cast and partially to make it more streamlined and, therefore, easier for a young audience to understand and follow.

(The scene that was cut is not specified, but it is one of the scenes in Act III, which normally has five scenes instead of four.)

The play is also available in the volume [*Abridged Shakespeare Collection: For Schools and Performance*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Abridged-Shakespeare-Collection-Schools-Performance/dp/1530513235/), which also contains *Twelfth Night*, *Macbeth*, *A Midsummer Night's Dream* and *Romeo and Juliet*.